# Polling function with recurision, ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, polling

```
function poll() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: "GameLogic",
            contentType: "application/json", 
            data: {
                type: "update",
                card: JSON.stringify("string")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('eroor');
            },
            complete: poll })
        }, 5000);
}
```

This function is supposed to send a request every 5 seconds and get alert the corresponding response. But it always alert with error. The request is handled by a servlet. I checked and confirmed that servlet receives the requests properly. This is the servlet code which handles the polling request.

```
String resp = "";
response.setContentType("application/json");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
if(request.getParameter("type").equals("update"))
{
    resp = "received";
}

out.write(resp);
```

I printed the resp string to the server log and it works as expected. Why doesn't the server reply with the response properly? The `error:` component is called because no response is received?

Answer (score 0):

```
String resp = "";
response.setContentType("application/json");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
if(request.getParameter("type").equals("update"))
{
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
    mainObject.put("value","received");
    resp = mainObject.toString();
}

out.write(resp);
```

Since the content type is set to "application/json", the `resp` string should be made from a json object format.